# ms-access: Why isn't this relationship not working?

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

just started today understanding relations between ms access databases. Can anyone figure out why this isnt working?

I can explain a lot in my way, but I think that the pictures says more then 1000 words

[image: tblINfo]
[image: tblOpdr]
[image: relations]
[image: tables]

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"?  What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I filled in two forms, 1st: tblKlntInfo and 2nd: 'tblRepOpdr'. In the 4th picture, there isn't any information in the unvolded part. I was expecting to see the input I made in 'tblRepOpdr' (as proof it's related)

Comment: Have you added a record to tblRepOpdr with a KlntID that also occurs in tblKlintInfo ?

Comment: yes, please look at the third picture

Comment: I did, and it only illustrates a record in tblKlintInfo, not in tblRepOpdr.

Comment: ahh excuse me, with record you mean a column inside the database tblRepOdr ? Isn't this vissible in the 2nd picture?

Comment: By record, I mean a line of data.

Comment: When you have a relationship set up, you get the little plus sign in your datasheet (third picture) and when you click the sign, you see all records with a matching relationship field (column). If there are no matching records, you can add them, which is indicated by the asterisk (*)

Comment: Maybe the problem is in you form and not your table setup?

Comment: @Jeff O - I do not believe there is a problem, just a quest for information.

Comment: I see, I thought because of the relationship, the primairy ID from tbl1 would be duplicated to the same ID in the second tbl. After adding a (the same) ID value to the second table, I did see more data. Is this because there is a match between pri key tbl and the second table key related or will any value do for the second tbl relation?

Comment: It's getting indeed clear now! :) @Jeff, first I thought that I didn't do something right, but I lacked knowledge about relations (with access ;-)) Great help :) Can you make an answer out of this Remou? After I'm done with this project, your reputation is sky high :)

Comment: The plus sign will only show related records. If you have used relational integrity, you can only add records to the 'many' table that have an identical foreign key (matching field) to the 'one' table. It is not a good idea to work with tables, you should use forms. If you set up a form based on the 'one' table and add a subform based on the 'many' table, the foreign key will be filled in automatically (the wizard will set the link child and master fields for you).

Comment: @Remou please make your comment as answer, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a relationship set up, you get the little plus sign in your datasheet (third picture) and when you click the sign, you see all records with a matching relationship field (column). If there are no matching records, you can add them, which is indicated by the asterisk (*)

The plus sign will only show related records. If you have used relational integrity, you can only add records to the 'many' table that have an identical foreign key (matching field) to the 'one' table. It is not a good idea to work with tables, you should use forms. If you set up a form based on the 'one' table and add a subform based on the 'many' table, the foreign key will be filled in automatically (the wizard will set the link child and master fields for you).